# Using trackBy with ngFor in angular 6 improve performance?

Tags: angular, performance, ngfor

Using trackBy with ngFor in angular 6 improve performance

```
 <app-analysis-item *ngFor="let element of analyses"
                     [analysis]="element"

     (deleteAnalysisEvent)="onAnalysisDeleted($event)">  
</app-analysis-item>


        If yes why angular team don't say that ????.
```

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#change-propagation

Comment: Thx for the answer. But not yet understand it's a best practice or no ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is improving performance by using trackBy in for loops,

if you know the concept of Virtual DOM in React or other technology, trackBy with ngFor exactly work like this

also, many of blogger has mentioned this:
[helpful link](https://blog.bitsrc.io/10-tricks-to-optimize-your-angular-app-44208f616bf0)

Answer (score 0):

Here we will use TrackBy with *ngFor to improve the performance of Web Application,
why because when data is loaded in the data Table. If any new record was added to that existing object, Again Dom will Renders total page again,
To overcome this issue we are using TrackBy, while when we adding new item to the existing object without Re-Rendering simply it will add new item into the existing list.